# Django 1.11 how can I construct a url lookup with a hash symbol?

Tags: python, django, django-1.11

Here is the constructor in question:

```
url(r"^app/#events/(?P<pk>\d+)$", views.app, name="app-event"),
```

There is a route to catch `app/`, so the problem is not that the server doesn't pick up the rest of the url. I know what the browser does there. We use this for links from reverse lookup.

My question is, in Django 1.8 it would leave the string alone, not parsing `#` to `%23`. In Django 1.11 it does parse, and I don't want it to.

Comment: what is the URL_PATTERNS supposed to do?

Comment: Add `url.replace('%23', '#')` to your code?

Comment: @Alasdair please don't guess at answers.

Comment: tbh, i would not put the fragment into the pattern. 1) it's confusing and misleading and 2) you can't avoid repeating yourself anyway, because to constract the target id you cannot use reverse or the url tag.

Comment: @hop it's not a guess at an answer, it's a suggestion. Django URL patterns shouldn't include `#`, so doing a string substitution might be the most practical answer.

Comment: @Alasdair what would `url` in your solution even be?

Comment: @hop `/app/%23events/4`, for example.

Comment: See https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25582 and https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-developers/_ZuTpMEATiM/discussion

Comment: @hop that was stuff for the primary key, which is a UUID in our case but for simplicity I represent it as a standard int here. Just forgot to remove it is all.